Maximise total length of the intervals in different thirds, whilst avoiding arithmetic progressions.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the family of subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such
that $X$ is a union of a finite family $\{X_i:i\in\mathcal I\}$  of
closed pairwise disjoint segments. Moreover, put
$\mu(X)=\displaystyle\sum_{i\in\mathcal I}\mu(X_i),$ where $\mu(X_i)$
is the length of the segment $X_i$ for each $i\in\mathcal I.$ I am
interested to bound the supremum $M=\mu(X)+\mu(Y)+\mu(Z),$ where
$X,Y,Z\in\mathcal I,\ X\subset[0,1],\ Y\subset[1,2],\ Z\subset[2,3],$
such that there is no arithmetic progression $(x,y,z)\in X×Y×Z.$

The best I could come up with was $X=[0,1],\ Y= \left[1,\frac{4}{3}\right], Z=\left[\frac{8}{3},3\right].$ But I'm not sure this is best, and even if it is, I don't know how to prove this is best.
Maybe this is correct, and our argument can be to split into different cases for the values of $\mu(X),\mu(Y),$ and $\mu(Z).$

The required supremum is $2$. Indeed, the lower bound follows when we put $X=[0,1]$, $Y=\varnothing$, and $Z=[0,1]$. But if you want $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ to be nonempty then for any natural number $n$ consider $X=[0,1-1/(n+1)]$, $Y=[2-2/(n+2),2]$, and $Z=[2,3-1/(n+1)]$. Then $\mu(X)+\mu(Z)\ge 2-2/(n+1)$.
To show the upper bound observe first that $\mu(X+Z)\ge\mu(X)+\mu(Z).$ Indeed, pick a natural number $n$ such that there exists nondecreasing sequences $(x_1,\dots, x_{2n})$ and $(z_1,\dots, z_{2n})$ with $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_{2i-1},x_{2i}]$ and $Z=\bigcup_{i=1}^n [z_{2i-1},z_{2i}]$. Then
$$\mu(X+Z)\ge \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_{2i-1}+z_{2i-1},x_{2i}+z_{2i}]\right)=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}+z_{2i}-x_{2i-1}-z_{2i-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}-x_{2i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^n z_{2i}-z_{2i-1}=$$ $$\mu(X)+\mu(Z).$$
Now if sets $X,Y,Z$ satisfy the question condition, then $Y\subset [1,2]\setminus \frac 12(X+Z)$,
so $$\mu(Y)\le 1-\frac 12\mu(X+Z)\le 1-\frac 12\left(\mu(X)+\mu(Z)\right).$$
Note that if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are nonempty, then the first inequality is strict.
Therefore $$\mu(X)+\mu(Y)+\mu(Z)\le $$
$$\mu(X)+1-\frac 12\left(\mu(X)+\mu(Z)\right)+\mu(Z)=$$
$$1+\frac 12\left(\mu(X)+\mu(Z)\right)\le $$
$$1+\frac 12(1+1)=2.$$
And if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are nonempty, then $\mu(X)+\mu(Y)+\mu(Z)<2$.

Yes, I wanted $X,Y, Z$ to be nonempty.

Your $X_n$ are overlapping, i.e. not disjoint. Have you made a typo somewhere, or should I read on?

@AdamRubinson I rewrote this fragment.

I think this more generally works with $X, Y, Z$ being compact (and since they're already bounded, we can just say they're closed), where we use this theorem for $\mu(X+Z)\ge\mu(X)+\mu(Z)$. The proof for the theorem is essentially the same as what you wrote up.
